# Get Actor Position After rotation on certain origin

Tags: libgdx

The position on actor from view is different from getX() and getY() value due to my setOrigin() and setRotation() method applied on the actor. But how to get the drawn position of my actor?

Comment: What draw position and what is the actor? For example do you want the center position of an Image actor or a corner position of a label? Please add a bit more details on what you need.

Comment: Hello, thanks for reading my question. I would like to find out the center position of image actor, but getX() and getY() will always give me the initial image position before any rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you rotate an actor, its coordinate system is also rotated, so the center remains at the same coordinates, which are `(width / 2, height / 2)`. But the coordinates of the image center in the parent's coordinate system is changed.

The Actor class provides many utility methods for converting between different coordinate systems. You can then convert the center coordinates from the actor's coordinates sytem to the parent's coordinate system with `localToParentCoordinates(Vector2)`, like this:

```java
Vector2 centerInParent = localToParentCoordinates(Vector2(image.width / 2, image.height / 2))
```

I didn't test it but it should work. Tell me if you have any trouble.

Comment: Thanks !! It works like charm!! So when we getposition of actor, it will always return actor local position?  Not very clear how the details run, but still very thanks for providing solution !

Comment: The actor `getX()` and `getY()` return the coordinates of the actor in its parent. A local position is a position in the actor coordinate system (rotated and translated like the actor).